# Can't able to perform two actions in a javascript on select box

Tags: javascript, select

Can't able to perform two actions (i.e,I need to disable and need to unselect the selected option from the select)

1. I have two select boxes i.e, select_one box is ('1','2','3') & select_two box is ('please select', 'test1', 'test2','test3'...etc)
2. and i have written onchange on the select_one box
3. when i selected option 1 or 3 from select_box dropdown then i need to unselect the current value from select_two box and need to display the 'please select' option and also i need to disable the select_two box.

```js
const checkFun = ( value ) => {
                            if( value == '1' || value == '3' )
                            {
                                document.getElementById("select_two").disabled = true;
                                document.getElementById("select_two").options[0].selected = "selected";
                            } else
                            {
                                document.getElementById("select_two").disabled= false
                            }    
                        }
```

```html
 Select One: <select name="testOne" id="select_one" onchange="checkFun( this.value )"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>

 Select Two: <select name="testTwo" id="select_two"><option value=""> - please select - </option><option value="test1">test1</option><option value="test2">test2</option><option value="test3">test3</option></select>
```

Thanks,
KK

Comment: Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can paste the code on codepen and share the link

Comment: Your code style was borderline unreadable. I've cleaned it up a bit, but it's really helpful to format and ask the question in a way that it's easy to read for the people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function checkFun(value) {
  const s2 = document.getElementById("select_two");

  s2.value = "";
  s2.disabled = (value == '1' || value == '3');
}
```

```html
<select name="test" id="select_one" onchange="checkFun( this.value )">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="test1" id="select_two" disabled>
  <option value=""> - please select -</option>
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
  <option value="test3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @TalESid yes its working on html. As i am doing php post, the second value is disabled and on the post its sending the old value. So i need to handle that in php side. But your disable code is very short so i am using this js

Answer (score 1):

add value attribute to - please select - option tag like value="0"

```
  <select id="select_one">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>

 <select id="select_two">
    <option value="0"> - please select - </option>
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
    <option value="test3">test3</option>
 </select> 

<script>
    const boxTwo = document.getElementById('select_two');   
    document.getElementById('select_one').addEventListener('change',function(){
            boxTwo.value = 0;
            if (this.value == 2) {
                boxTwo.disabled = false;
            }else{
                boxTwo.disabled = true;
            }
    },{passive:true});
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried the above code, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: @KaifKhan I edited my answer please check now and please don't forget to upvote and accept if that will help you))

Comment: Hi @redevil, your code is good, But once it disabled we can't enable again when we chage to option '2'

Comment: @KaifKhan script edited try now

Answer (score 1):

it is working as expected!

```js
const checkFun = (value) => {
  if (value == '1' || value == '3') {
    document.getElementById("select_two").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("select_two").options[0].selected = true;

  } else {
    document.getElementById("select_two").disabled = false
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="test1" id="select_two">
  <option value=""> - please select -</option>
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
  <option value="test3">test3</option>
</select>

<select name="test" id="select_one" onchange="checkFun( this.value )">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No its not, I have run your code on 'Run code snippet' the value of the is not unselecting. ( i.e, I have selected test2 then when i select '1' on the second dropdown i need disable and also the test2 value should be deselect in that place i need 'please select' option.

Comment: Please check now !

Comment: Thanks @tushar yes its working on html. As i am doing php post, the second value is disabled and on the post its sending the old value. So i need to handle that in php side

Comment: Yeah , I was expecting the upvote :)